# Modify Html form submit output

Tags: html, forms, url, get

This is certainly a beginners question, but I was looking for an answer for quite some time. I want to use the following html to control one of my projects. When I hit the submit button the values are added to the url. That's exactly what I want, but I would like to modify the attached string, to make parsing it easier. The html below generates this url:

```
[...]/Interface.html?tail=3&speed=45&col1=37&col2=210
```

but I'd like the output look more like this:

```
[...]/Interface.html?tail=3&speed=45&col1=37&col2=210&end
```

In short: How do I format the attachment to the url which is added after submitting it with the GET-method?

```html
<title>Alu foil installation</title>
<meta name="generator" content="Bluefish 2.2.10">
<meta name="author" content="">
<meta name="date" content="">
<meta name="copyright" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="content-style-type" content="text/css">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">



<h1>Alu foil installation</h1>
<form>
  <p>
    <label for="ftail">Tail length:</label><br>
    <select name="tail" id="ftail">

      <option value="0">No tail</option>
      <option value="1">Short tail</option>
      <option value="2">Medium tail</option>
      <option value="3">Long tail</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="speed">Set the speed:</label><br>
    <input type="range" id="speed" name="speed" min="0" max="50">
  </p>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Color selection:</legend>
    <p>
      <label for="color1">Color 1 hue:</label>

      <input type="range" id="color1" name="col1" min="0" max="255">
    </p>
    <label for="color2">Color 2 hue:</label>

    <input type="range" id="color2" name="col2" min="0" max="255">
  </fieldset>

  <input type="submit" value="OK">

</form>
```

Comment: This is an X/Y problem. Why would you want to abuse the URL structure just to make it "easier" to parse on the server? The server knows each value in the GET parameter or the request array

Comment: I am running this on an ESP32 using arduino IDE. I'd like to use the values to feed them to my arduino sketch.

Comment: I am curious. Does my answer work in your environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

introduce a hidden variable `end`

```
<input type="hidden" name="end" value="" />
```

(an additional `=` willl be attached to `end`)

Comment: Which would either not be sent or give `&end=`

Comment: Or just this `<input type="submit" name="end" value="OK">`

Comment: or even `<input type="hidden" name="end" value="end" />`  :-)

Comment: This all works for me. Thank you very much. I didn't come up with the idea of using a hidden input type ... Great!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your Arduino or ESP32 can do, this is a clean solution

Submitting:

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const sp = new URLSearchParams(new FormData(this)).toString();
    console.log("/Interface.html?"+sp+"&end"); // send this
  })
})
```

```html
<title>Alu foil installation</title>
<meta name="generator" content="Bluefish 2.2.10">
<meta name="author" content="">
<meta name="date" content="">
<meta name="copyright" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="content-style-type" content="text/css">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">



<h1>Alu foil installation</h1>
<form>
  <p>
    <label for="ftail">Tail length:</label><br>
    <select name="tail" id="ftail">

      <option value="0">No tail</option>
      <option value="1">Short tail</option>
      <option value="2">Medium tail</option>
      <option value="3">Long tail</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="speed">Set the speed:</label><br>
    <input type="range" id="speed" name="speed" min="0" max="50">
  </p>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Color selection:</legend>
    <p>
      <label for="color1">Color 1 hue:</label>

      <input type="range" id="color1" name="col1" min="0" max="255">
    </p>
    <label for="color2">Color 2 hue:</label>

    <input type="range" id="color2" name="col2" min="0" max="255">
  </fieldset>

  <input type="submit" value="OK">

</form>
```

On change

```js
//let url = new URL(location.href) // if you need to save it
let tId;
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("change",function(e) {
    clearTimeout(tId); // they are fiddling
    const sp = new URLSearchParams(new FormData(this)).toString()+"&end";
    //url.search=sp
    tId = setTimeout(function() { location.search = sp }, 2000); // allow the user to modify the controles
  })
})
```

```html
<title>Alu foil installation</title>
<meta name="generator" content="Bluefish 2.2.10">
<meta name="author" content="">
<meta name="date" content="">
<meta name="copyright" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="content-style-type" content="text/css">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">



<h1>Alu foil installation</h1>
<form>
  <p>
    <label for="ftail">Tail length:</label><br>
    <select name="tail" id="ftail">

      <option value="0">No tail</option>
      <option value="1">Short tail</option>
      <option value="2">Medium tail</option>
      <option value="3">Long tail</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="speed">Set the speed:</label><br>
    <input type="range" id="speed" name="speed" min="0" max="50">
  </p>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Color selection:</legend>
    <p>
      <label for="color1">Color 1 hue:</label>

      <input type="range" id="color1" name="col1" min="0" max="255">
    </p>
    <label for="color2">Color 2 hue:</label>

    <input type="range" id="color2" name="col2" min="0" max="255">
  </fieldset>


</form>
```

Comment: I am really new to html and stuff, sorry. Could you please tell me where to put the first block (starting with "window.addEventListener")? Does it go to an external file or is it embedded in the html file defined in you 2nd block? Apart from that: is there a possibility to change the "addEventListener("submit",function(e) " to modify the url every time the user does an input (e.g. the user moves a slider) without the necessity to press the "submit" button every time? This would be amazing...

Comment: the first block can go as it is into an external js file. If you call that jscode.js, then you need to add `<script src="jscode.js"></script>` to the head of the HTML. If you want to embed it, just wrap the first block in `<script> /* block here */</script>` and put that in the head of the HTML

Comment: Thank you a lot for your patience, @mplungjan! Any hint how I can make the EventListener to react to mere user input instead of the need to hit the submit button (see above).

Comment: I added a second example. I have a feeling you MIGHT want to update an iFrame instead of reloading the page

Comment: Thank you again. I will try that solution soon and report back!

Comment: I tried the 2nd example. On user input it changes the url as it is intended. But after abt 2 seconds the browser (Firefox v68) shows an error message: "Firefox can’t find the file at /Interface.html?tail=1&speed=25&col1=128&col2=67&end."

Comment: I found that the script changes the path to the html file from "file:///home/[User]/Desktop/Projects/Alu-Installation/test2.html" to "file:///Interface.html?tail=3&speed=25&col1=128&col2=128&end". And because there is no such file it throws an error. How can I set the script to leave the path alone without specifying an absolute path in the script?

Comment: Thank you again, mplungjan - it works! Two (hopefully) last questions: The form resets after every change. So when I move one slider it submits, but the slider is moving back to the middle position. I'd like to stay all the values at their last position/selection. Additionally I would like the submit occur on every user input instead of change. So ideally the the url change should happen instantly when the user moves the slider not just when she/he releases it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That’s why I suggested an all frame. I throttle the user input because a server access should not be on every pixel change - unless that is what you need. There will bee too much lag if we have to store and re-read the values on submits that occur every millisecond